# Finding overlapping time periods in python

Tags: python

I have two lists of two different kinds of "events" (listA and listB), with each event having a time period over which it takes place (stored as start time and duration in seconds), and I want to find all events from listA that happened at the same time as any event that happened in listB.

The events don't need to have happened for the exact same time and same duration, if there is any overlap in time that will count. Also, there is no overlap within a list lists, at any given second there is *at most* one event from listA and one event from listB running. Finally, all events in listB *must* happen within an event from listA (it can start and end at the same time as the event in listA, but cannot start before it or end after it). In other words, all listB events are fully enclosed inside listA events, and listA events will have `0` to `n` listB events contained within them.

Now, I was thinking I could do a set-intersection for each item in listB compared to each item in listA, but that seems really inefficient, is there an **efficient** way of finding all such overlaps?

Sample lists:

```
listA=[
    {
      "duration": 3600,
      "starttime": "1/31/2019 5:00",
      "listAData": "..."
    },
    {
     "duration": 1800,
     "starttime": "1/31/2019 7:00"
     "listAData": "..."
    },
    {...},
  ]
listB=[
    {
      "duration": 1800,
      "starttime": "1/31/2019 5:15",
      "listBData": "..."
    },
    {
     "duration": 60,
     "starttime": "2/1/2019 23:00"
     "listBData": "..."
    }
  ]
```

So in this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpK3c.png)
I would get A1 and A3 (because they are overlapping with B1 and B2 respectively), while A2 would be ignored.

I also don't care if A1 is overlapped with multiple B objects, so I really only need a list of all listA events that happen at the same time as at least one listB event, or a list of their indexes or whatever.

Comment: To my understanding your textual description contradicts with the graphic. So B's are _always_ fully enclosed by A's, and A's contain `0` to `n` B's? Is that correct?

Comment: that is correct yes, not sure where I contradict that in the text?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of code that shows a fairly generic class I wrote (long ago). It's not much, but hopeful it will at least provide you a starting point for developing your own.

```
class Interval(object):
    # Representation of a closed interval.
    # a & b can be numeric, dates, or any other object type than can be
    # compared. if the type can also be incremented by 1, then it will be
    # possible to iterate between the two values in ascending order.
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        #self.lowerbound, self.upperbound = min(a, b), max(a, b)
        #self.lowerbound, self.upperbound = sorted([a, b])  # Py v2.4
        self.lowerbound, self.upperbound = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)  # Py v2.5

    def __contains__(self, val):
        return self.lowerbound <= val <= self.upperbound

    # Implemented as a generator (so no 'next' method needed)
    def __iter__(self):
        nextvalue = self.lowerbound  # initialize iteration state
        while nextvalue <= self.upperbound:
            yield nextvalue
            nextvalue += 1
```